# perform default action of a link inside of callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, onclick

I have a link to login with facebook on my page and I want to manipulate the way the onclick works. Currently I have changed it so that it does not do the default action by adding return false to the end:

```
$('#login').on('click', function(e) {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        //window.easyUserData.login = response;
        if (response.authResponse) {
            console.log('authorised');
            return true;
        } else {
            // cancelled
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

What was happening was that right after it called FB.login to open the dialog it would redirect the page, not what I wanted. What i am looking for is for it to do the default action of the link where i put return true. The return true bit doesn't work because by the time it gets there, return false has already been processed. Any tips on how to do this?

The link has href="#/home" and I am using backbone.js to handle routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to asynchronous nature of your login function you would have to use a javscript redirect:

```
$('#login').on('click', function(e) {
    var href=this.href;
    FB.login(function(response) {
        //window.easyUserData.login = response;
        if (response.authResponse) {
            console.log('authorised');
            /* redirect here*/
           window.location=href;
        } else {
            // cancelled
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```